# COUNT of GROUPS and NULLs don't add up to total rows in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, audit

The `COUNT` of `GROUPS` and `NULL`s don't add up to total rows in the table.

I first wondered, maybe the SQL Server total row count could be off (I'm new), so I thought to do a double-check by running a `COUNT` on the `RentalID` column, then checked for `DISTINCT` values just to verify that the total number of rows in the table called `AllData` was accurate. All results concurred; the table has a total of 3,471,007 rows.

Then I ran `COUNT` on all values in the `Gender` column using `GROUP BY`, and then separately ran a `COUNT` of the `NULL`s in that column. I expected when I added the three together, the figure would match the total number of rows in the table, but it doesn't. It's off by 3,444.

Here's a copy of my code:

```
-- HOW MANY TOTAL ROWS IN THE TABLE?  -------------------------------
SELECT  *
FROM AllData
-- 3,471,007 rows 

-- HOW MANY total RentalIDs ARE THERE?  -----------------------------
SELECT RentalID
FROM AllData
-- 3,471,007 rows. 

-- How many UNIQUE RentalIDs ARE THERE?  ----------------------------
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(RentalID))
FROM AllData
-- 3,471,007 rows. Means no missing RentalIDs.


-- HOW IS GENDER POPULATED?
SELECT Gender, COUNT(Gender) AS GenderCount
FROM AllData
GROUP BY Gender
/* Results:
   Gender  GenderCount
   NULL    0
   Male    2174743
   Female  737307
*/

-- HOW MANY ROWS ARE MISSING GENDER?  -------------------------------
SELECT  Gender
FROM AllData
WHERE Gender IS NULL
-- 562,401 rows are empty.


/* Why don't these numbers add up to total rows in table?
   2,174,743 Count of Gender = Male
     737,307 Count of Gender = Female
     562,401 Count of Gender = NULL
   3,474,451 This should equal total rows in table, but it doesn't

   3,471,007 Total rows in table
       3,444 Difference: these rows not accounted for...  */
```

Comment: Something doesn't make sense, because when you `group by` gender, you get 0 rows for null, whereas you should get 562,401 based on your following query.

Comment: How can I investigate why the NULL is returning 0?

Comment: Change `count(Gender)` to `count(*)` - when you specify a column name it ignores nulls.

Comment: Ah! So, making that change, the results returned 558,957 which doesn't match the results from the query where gender is null.

Comment: Gender data type is (nvarchar(50), null)

Comment: @LisaNV Can you add the modified query to your question along with the number of rows.

Comment: Do a `select distinct gender from alldata` then `select count(*) from alldata where gender = ?` for each of the unique value found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(Gender) AS GenderCount
FROM AllData
GROUP BY Gender
```

The above statement is giving 0 against `NULL` in gender because the `COUNT` function will not count the `NULL` values. So Instead, You can go for any of the below approaches

**Recommended Approach**

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(1) AS GenderCount
FROM AllData
GROUP BY Gender
```

**Alternative #1**

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(*) AS GenderCount
    FROM AllData
    GROUP BY Gender
```

**Alternative #2**

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(ISNULL(Gender,'')) AS GenderCount
    FROM AllData
    GROUP BY Gender
```

Comment: Why is `COUNT(1)` the recommended approach? You are telling the DBMS to generate the expression `1` for every row in the table and check whether this expression results in NULL or must be counted. All you want to do is count rows, which is a mere `COUNT(*)`. Use `COUNT(<expression>)` only for expressions that can be null and where you only want to count the non-null occurrences.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Because in SQL Server, `COUNT(someconstant)` is compiled the same as `COUNT(*)`, you can verify this by looking at the query plan. And some prefer `COUNT(1)` as it makes it more obvious that every row is counted

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes, I know that SQL Server has an optimizer that detects `COUNT(someconstant)` and luckily converts this to `COUNT(*)` for us. But how is "count ones" more obvious then "count rows"? It isn't in my opinion. We could also use `SUM(1)` which adds up rows until it gets a total row count. But I wouldn't use this either. If I want to count rows, I use "COUNT rows" (`COUNT(*)`  in SQL); if I want to count some expresssion, I use `COUNT(expression)`. Well, I just don't get the point, it seems :D